# SSAS MDX Calculated Measure - COUNT of [ITEMS].[Item] grouped [Items].[Item Group]

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

In Excel connected to SSAS, I am trying to build a pivot table and add a custom Measure Calculation using "OLAP Tools" and/or "OLAP Pivot Table Exensions".  I am trying to add a calculation that is really simple in my mind, but I cannot get it to work.  The calc I need is:

> GOAL: A record count of the [Items] dimension records grouped by any of the
>   [Items] dimension fields.

In particular I am trying to group by `[Items].[Items Groups]` and `[Items].[Item]`.  Item is the lowest grain, so the count should return value "1".  I have created a couple calculations that are kind of in the ballpark (see below).  But the calcs don't appears to be working as desired.

**What I have tried:**

> Attempt #1 -- **`[Measures].[Items Count (With net amount values)]`**
>
> ```
> DISTINCTCOUNT( {[Items].[Item].MEMBERS} )
> ```
>
> The calc 'Items Count (With net amount values)' appears to be
>   returning a decent count value, but it appears it only counts the Item
>   if there are transnational records found (not sure why).  Also, when
>   at the lowest grain level the calc returns that value for the parent
>   group, not the dimension level selected on the rows.
>
> Attempt #2 -- **`[Measures].[Items Count (All)]`**
>
> ```
> [Items].[Item].[Item].Count
> ```
>
> This calc returns the TOTAL item count for the entire dimension
>   regardless of the dimension level placed on the rows.
>
> Attempt #3 -- **`[Measures].[Items Count]`**
>
> ```
> COUNT ( { [Items].[Item].MEMBERS}, EXCLUDEEMPTY)
> ```
>
> This calc freezes up Excel and I have to quit Excel.  No idea why.  I have seen this sytnax recommended on a few different sites.

**Screenshot:**

Help please?  This seems really simple, but I am not very skilled with MDX.  In DAX and SSAS TABULAR this would be very simple expression.  But I'm struggling to count the rows with MDX in SSAS MD.

The "Outside Purchased Beef" group has 18 items with transactions, but 41 items in total.  I do not know how to calculate the "41" value.

*SSAS Excel-CalcMeasure-CountRows.png*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following samples on AdventureWorks.

```
with member [Measures].[CountTest]
as 
count(existing  [Product].[Subcategory].members - [Product].[Subcategory].[All])
select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[CountTest]
}
on columns,
{
([Product].[Category].[Category]
,[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory] -- comment this line for the second result
)
}
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Now comment the indicated line for the parent view.

[image]

Comment: Second screenshot is the same

Comment: Thanks!  I tried `COUNT(existing [Items].[Item].MEMBERS )`... that was really close but somehow returned a count of 1 extra at every level-- such as "2 instead of 1" and "42 instead of 41".  Then I tried closer to what you had demonstrated: 'COUNT(existing [Items].[Item].MEMBERS - [Items].[Item].[All])'.  I think that did it!